# PHP output JSON Web Service charset UTF-8 error

Tags: php, json, web-services, encoding, hebrew

I am hosting a web service in JSON output by PHP.

I have **Hebrew** data set in DB and I am posting this as an output to Web service.

When I post the data initially it output the result as follows:

**JSON:**

```
{
    "tasklist": [
        {
            "customerID": "9936",
            "name": "×˜×¨ ××¨×ž×” ×™×–×•× ×•×‘×™× ×•×™ ×‘×¢"×ž",
            "cargo":"××‘×¨×¨",
            "destination":"×ž×›×¨", 
            "quantity":"1.000000",
            "startdate":"03/01/201300: 00: 00" 
        }
               ]
}
```

But this `"××‘×¨×¨"` can be readable by Android/Iphone parser and convert it to original Hebrew. But i faced Error in  `"name": "×˜×¨ ××¨×ž×” ×™×–×•× ×•×‘×™× ×•×™ ×‘×¢"×ž",`. where `"` is in between the string so the JSON is not valid and shows error!

[image]

To Over come this issue I used `UTF-8` to convert `"××‘×¨×¨"` this to Hebrew `"נברר"`. But in this case too the problem remains same:

**PHP:**

> header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

**JSON:**

```
{
    "tasklist": [
        {
            "customerID": "9936",
            "name": "טר ארמה יזום ובינוי בע"מ",
            "cargo":"נברר",
            "destination":"מכר",
            "quantity":"1.000000",
            "startdate":"03/01/201300: 00: 00"
        }
                ]
}
```

But still the problem remains:

[image]

Also in some case I am getting this `�` because of using UTF-8

```
"name":"מחצבות כפר גלעדי-חומרי מ�"
```

- How can I overcome this issue?
- Is there any other specific encode I need to use?

Note: The data cannot be changes in Database The solution should be while output to JSON.

How the data stored in DB is shown below:

> name
>
> ×ž×—×¦×‘×•×ª ×›×¤×¨ ×’×œ×¢×“×™-×—×•×ž×¨×™ ×ž×

My PHP Script which output JSON:

```
<?php

//My DB connection and Query comes here

$jsontext = '{"tasklist":[';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryExe)){
$jsontext .= '{"customerID":"'.$row['AUTO_ID'].'",';
$jsontext .='"name":"'.$row['Customer_Name'].'",';
$jsontext .='"cargo":"'.$row['Type_of_Cargo'].'",';
$jsontext .='"destination":"'.$row['Destination'].'",';
$jsontext .='"quantity":"'.$row['Quantity'].'",';
$jsontext .='"startdate":"'.$row['startdate'].'"},';
}
$jsontext = substr_replace($jsontext, '', -1); // to get rid of extra comma
$jsontext .= "]}";

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//Output the final JSON
echo $jsontext;

?>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Was the question clear? to understand my issue.

Comment: how are you creating your json? I would do the following: 1. read values from db, 2. convert each value to utf8 using utf8_encode, 3. put it into a php array and finally 4. do json_encode and echo

Comment: @steven I have posted my PHP script have a look at it. I am not encoding initially only while output to web service I change the header!

Comment: setting the header is not enough. You need utf8_encoded strings. You get them by using utf8_encode if your db-field is not utf8.

Comment: @steven my DB field is utf8_general_ci

Comment: This has to do with `mysql` but there's no tag about it. I supose many people end up here looking for: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` or `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your db-field is utf8 you should fist do:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

**You should always do the 'SET NAMES...' before inserting your data, too.
Be sure that you really stored utf8 encoded strings!**

then do your query:

```
mysql_query($your_query);

$array = array("tasklist"=>array());    

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryExe)){
        $a = array();
        $a["customerID"] = $row['AUTO_ID'];
        $a["name"] = $row['Customer_Name'];
        $a["cargo"] = $row['Type_of_Cargo'];
        $a["destination"] = $row['Destination'];
        $a["quantity"] = $row['Quantity'];
        $a["startdate"] = $row['startdate'];
        $array["tasklist"][] = $a;
}

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

echo json_encode($array);
exit();
```

i've made the experience that these is not enough when the servers default charset is for example iso. In that case i need to do the following in my .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: can you check I have added the JSON output for your code. near name "x" it cannot be parsed in Android / iphone?

Comment: {
    "tasklist": [
        {
            "customerID": "9936",
            "name": "××¨ ××¨×× ×××× ×××× ×× ××¢\"×",
            "cargo": "× ××¨×¨",
            "destination": "×××¨",
            "quantity": "1.000000",
            "startdate": "03/01/2013 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: hmmm the documentation of utf8_encode says that data shoud be an ISO-8859-1 string. I dont think that your string is such. you should tell us what the encoding of your db-field is. I would recommend utf8 and in that case you should `SET NAMES 'utf8'` like @BigToach sayed. In that case you don't need to utf8_encode with php. Hope it helps.

Comment: my DB field is utf8_general_ci  I even tried BigToach method but still same error..

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to use json_encode. You need to pass it properly utf8 encoded data.

If you are using MySQL you can try running the following before your query to get your data.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

You can also look into using [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

Comment: BigToach mysql_set_charset('utf8'); still same issue :( any idea?

Comment: Did you try changing your code to use json_encode instead of generating it yourself as well?

Comment: Yes.. I did as per the another answer and mingled your code in it.. but same error.. JSON validation error only in names.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#100565

> That said, quotes " will produce invalid JSON, but this is only an issue if you're using json_encode() and just expect PHP to magically escape your quotes. You need to do the escaping yourself.

May be you can replace `"`  with `\"`  , i guess it will solve the issue.

Source : [PHP JSON String, escape Double Quotes for JS output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462394/php-json-string-escape-double-quotes-for-js-output)